# How to update hasChanges when property value changes

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this class:

```
    export class Team {
    id:number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    hasChanges:boolean;
}
```

How do I wire this up so that `hasChanges` is set to true when name or description changes?

Comment: I would suggest creating get property for name and description. Then change hasChanges to true manually when name or description is changed. Not good solution, but workable

Comment: I was thinking there was some way to subscribe to the changes.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way in Typescript directly. But I know a library 'RsJs' that creates Observable variables and then you can subscribe when values change.

Comment: https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html   this might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the aforementioned methods. *Or* use Object.defineProperty to set a getter/setter for the description. This would let you change that other value when the description changes.

```
var obj = { hasChanged: false }, description = "";
Object.defineProperty(obj, "description", {
  get: function() { return description; },
  set: function(value) { description = value; obj.hasChanged = true; }
});
```

Comment: That looks great, I am going to try it.